# checking if number entered is a digit in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a simple `textbox` in which users enter number.

Does jQuery have a `isDigit` function that will allow me to show an alert box if users enter something other than digits?

The field can have decimal points as well.

Comment: so you mean *numbers* and not *digits* ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I would suggest using regexes:

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
if(intRegex.test(str) || floatRegex.test(str)) {
   alert('I am a number');
   ...
}
```

Or with a single regex as per @Platinum Azure's suggestion:

```
var numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;
var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
if(numberRegex.test(str)) {
   alert('I am a number');
   ...
}
```

Comment: the number can have decimals also. 5001.10 should be acceptable

Comment: Should have specified that. :-) You can use a regex like this for ALL (well, many) possible numbers: `/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/` This will allow for decimals, signs, and even scientific notation on the end if you want. You can remove various parts as you need to (Google Perl-style regular expressions if you need help figuring out which part is what, but it should be fairly intuitive).

Answer (score 78):

Forget regular expressions.  JavaScript has a builtin function for this: `isNaN()`:

```
isNaN(123)           // false
isNaN(-1.23)         // false
isNaN(5-2)           // false
isNaN(0)             // false
isNaN("100")         // false
isNaN("Hello")       // true
isNaN("2005/12/12")  // true
```

Just call it like so:

```
if (isNaN( $("#whatever").val() )) {
    // It isn't a number
} else {
    // It is a number
}
```

Comment: isNaN won't ensure your input doesn't contain whitespace. isNaN(" 42 ") === false

Comment: You can trim the whitespace with something like : YouValue.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

More trim implementations : http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

Comment: Interesting approach, but personally I think the regex is clearer than the double negative (not a Not-a-Number is a number). Although I'd be inclined to put the regex into a nice utility function isDigit().

Comment: @karim79: it's not the case that isNaN won't accept a string argument. isNaN("42") returns false, isNaN("42.2") returns false, isNaN("42.2.3") returns true. The documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/isNaN states that "isNaN attempts to convert the passed parameter to a number. If the parameter can't be converted, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false".

Comment: isNaN() is not reliable function to check valid numbers because it also returns false for boolean values for e.g. isNaN(true) -> return value = false

Answer (score 13):

there is a simpler way of checking if a variable is an integer. you can use $.isNumeric() function. e.g.

```
$.isNumeric( 10 );     // true
```

this will return true but if you put a string in place of the 10, you will get false.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: `The signature '(value: any): boolean' of '$.isNumeric' is deprecated.ts(6387)`

Answer (score 2):

Following script can be used to check whether value is valid integer or not.

```
  function myFunction() {
    var a = parseInt("10000000");
    if (!isNaN(a) && a <= 2147483647 && a >= -2147483647){
    alert("is integer"); 
    } else {
     alert("not integer"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Value validation wouldn't be a responsibility of jQuery. You can use pure JavaScript for this. Two ways that come to my mind are:

```
/^\d+$/.match(value)
Number(value) == value
```

Comment: Since your second example uses == and not ===, wouldn't type coercion on the right-hand-side cause the expression to be true always?

Comment: Don't know why no-one upvoated this answer. I used Number(value).... Its perfect.

Comment: @systemPAUSE The mention of user input and "digits" makes me think that the value is a string and the reason for the `==`.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery's [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin you could do something like this, assuming that the form is called *form* and the value to validate is called *nrInput*

```
$("form").validate({
            errorElement: "div",
            errorClass: "error-highlight",
            onblur: true,
            onsubmit: true,
            focusInvalid: true,
            rules:{
                'nrInput': {
                    number: true,
                    required: true
                }
            });
```

This also handles decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.isNumeric = function() {
    var s = this.replace(',', '.').replace(/\s+/g, '');
return s == 0 || (s/s);
}
```

usage

```
'9.1'.isNumeric() -> 1
'0xabc'.isNumeric() -> 1
'10,1'.isNumeric() -> 1
'str'.isNumeric() -> NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourfield = $('fieldname').val();

if($.isNumeric(yourfield)) { 
        console.log('IM A NUMBER');
} else { 
        console.log('not a number');
}
```

JQUERY DOCS:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a set of JavaScript functions, right? So you could use JavaScript's regular expression support to validate the string. You can put this in a jQuery callback if you like, too, since those just take anonymously-declared function bodies and the functions are still JavaScript.

Link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    $("#cust_zip").keypress(function (e) {
        //var z = document.createUserForm.cust_mobile1.value;
        //alert(z);
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

            $("#errmsgzip").html("Digits Only.").show().fadeOut(3000);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation rather than just posting code?