# jQuery - Inputmask plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hei

Have anyone idea of input mask in jquery For example a field must have three letters followed by 4 numbers. cda1234. If one writes something in the field that does not fit with this must be removed continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooked an fast example up, see: http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSg/2/

Checks for non integers for the first 3 characters, and then only accept integers.

Could proberbly be made wiser with regex, but this should give a starting point :)

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.length <= 3) {
       char = value.substring(value.length - 1);
        if(!(isNaN(char))) {
            var newval = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
            $(this).val(newval);
        }
    }
    if(value.length > 3) {
       char = value.substring(value.length - 1);
        if(isNaN(char)) {
            var newval = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
            $(this).val(newval);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: which reference of jquery i need to add in header tag ?

Comment: What do you mean? Add the jquery lib to you header, and the script inside  `$(document).ready(function() {
  // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });`

Comment: if i want this function onBlur how to do that ?? instead of keyup

Comment: just replace `keyup` with `blur` - but it will only "check" your input when you leave the input field then :)

Comment: ya that i want . iam trying this but its not validating when i leave text box, iam calling like this onblur="CheckInputMask(this)". and i have puted above code iside function CheckInputMask() {  here above code} but it seems not working when i leave the textbox

Comment: Thanks one thing more here after characters when i write 1234555 i dont give error message i want just like  cda 123 . means cda space 123

Comment: So it can only be 3 letters - a space - 3 numbers ( "cda 123" ) ?

Comment: Ya correct . if user dont write correct in textbox then i wud like to show a message format is not correct

Comment: Ya correct . if user dont write correct in textbox then i wud like to show a message format is not correct . also i it should not remove uncorrect format from textbox .just want to show a message to user that format is not correct soo user can write correct. instead of removing from textbox

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the [Masked Input Plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there these links should give you the building blogs on how to achieve this.

First, select the first 3 charectors, here is how:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

then check if they are numbers:
[checking if number entered is a digit in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272696/checking-if-number-entered-is-a-digit-in-jquery)

And so on...

Comment: I was recently admonished to avoid w3schools at all costs, as the website's incorrectness is legendary according to http://w3fools.com/. I thought I'd pass it along. The link you use may be thoroughly adequate, however.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to implement masks with mixed digit types on jQuery Mask Plugin (github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Your will look like this: 
`$('.your-field').mask('SSS0000')`

And its all set. The plugin will take care of invalid input and everything.

Cheers,
Igor.