# Dynamic keyboard capture for bank accounts

Tags: jquery

I want to create a jquery for capturing an input box and write it in bank format. I mean:

A Spanish bank format is like follows:

**0000 - 0000 - 00 - 0000000000**

4 digits, 4 more digits, 2 digits, and finally 10 digits.

I want to create or find a jquery that, when you introduce the numbers, it puts the **-** dynamically while typing the numbers on your keyboards.

Does anybody know any jquery that does that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935233/jquery-inputmask-plugin

Comment: Here is a jQuery plugin that does what you need btw: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, add it as an answer and I will vote you :)