# How to output the number 2.00 as a complete string?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Before this, i want to say sorry. But this is not duplicate. Any answer on other posting has same problem. No float or int in JS (only number). When you make `isInt()` function, 2.00 always detected `true` as integer. I want 2.00 detected as float. So, i have to stringify it first.

```
function isInt(i) {
    if ( i.toFixed ) {
        if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
            return true; // the problem is 2.00 always detected true as integer. 
            // i want 2.00 detected as float
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then i think i will stringify the 2.00 and then split it with split('.') . But toString doesn't do it

```
var i = 2.00;
alert(i.toString()); 
// Why this always result 2 . i want the character behind point
```

So, how to do that? i want 2.00 result "2.00" , not only "2"

Thank you for answering

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string is a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467542/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-float)

Comment: `2.00 === 2; // true`, if you want 2.d.p. see answers, if you want the number of decimal places that you typed in the literal, _JavaScript_ doesn't care and will drop zeros

Comment: Numerically, 2.00 == 2.  How is JS supposed to know you want what looks to it like useless 0s, without you explicitly telling it?

Comment: @Mangiucugna Sorry, this is not duplicate,

Comment: Only one type of number exists in javascript: IEEE 754 double precision floating-point. @NULL has the correct answer.

Comment: i knew only number. but when you create isInt function, 2.00 will always detected as int, not float. how to solve this?

Comment: @SlametBedjo: Simplist answer: you can't within the confines of javascript. There is **no way** to discriminate `2` from `2.0` `2.00` or even `2.0000000000000`.

Comment: @SlametBedjo Maybe if you treat your number as a string `var i = "2.00"` you could detect the comma and therefore detect if it's a float.

Comment: @SlametBedjo ... But you will lose all the functionality with numbers, eq: `"2.00" + "3.00" === "2.003.00"`

Comment: @SlametBedjo Acutally, as Llepwryd pointed out, JavaScript has floats only. I really don't see why you are even trying to implement an `isInt` for such a case as it makes no sense. NULL has the perfect answer for the string conversion problem. `isInt` however strongly suggests that your question is in fact a duplicate of the above mentioned question. Could you please tell why treating `2` and `2.00` (the very same values) differently is so important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to revision:

Within javascript there is **absolutely no way** to distinguish between `2` `2.0` and `2.000`. Therefore, you will **never** without some additional decimal place supplied, be able to detect from `var a = 2.00` that 2 was ever anything other than an `integer` (per your method) after it's been assigned.

Case in point, despite the [misleading] built-in methods:

```
typeof parseInt('2.00', 10) == typeof parseFloat('2.00')
                   'number' == 'number'
                        /* true */
```

#### Original Answer:

JavaScript doesn't have hard-based scalar types, just simply a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). For that reason, and because you really only have 1 significant figure, JavaScript is taking your `2.00` and making it an "integer" [used loosly] (therefore no decimal places are present). To JavaScript: `2 = 2.0 = 2.00 = 2.00000`).

Case in point, if I gave you the number `12.000000000000` and asked you to remember it and give it to someone a week from now, would you spend the time remember how many zeros there were, or focus on the fact that I handed you the number `12`? (`twelve` takes a lot less effort to remember than `twelve with as many decimal places`)

As far as `int` vs `float`/`double`/`real`, you're really only describing the type of number from your perspective and not JavaScript's. Think of calling a number in JavaScript an `int` as giving it a label and not a definition. to outline:

```
Value:     To JavaScript:    To Us:
------     --------------    ------
1          Number            integer
1.00       Number            decimal
1.23       Number            decimal
```

No matter what we may classify it as, JavaScript still only sees it as a `Number`.

If you need to keep decimal places, [`Number.toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is going to be your best bet.

For example:

```
// only 1 sig-fig
var a = 2.00;
console.log(''+a);             // 2
console.log(a.toFixed(2));     // 2.00

// 3 sig-figs
var b = 2.01
console.log(''+b);            // 2.01
console.log(b.toFixed(2));    // 2.01
```

BTW, prefixing the var with `''+` is the same as calling a `.toString()`, it's just cast just shorthand. The same outcome would result if I had used `a.toString()` or `b.toString()`

Comment: Javascript only has one numerical data-type, that is Number. toFixed only converts it to a string with the desired number of decimal places.

Comment: I wasn't implying it had `float` v `decimal` vs `real` vs `int`; Just that there is no hard-set data types. also, you're correct: it results in a string with a force-fixed number of decimal places.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The case is 2.00 should be detected as float. When every posting create isInt() , 2.00 always `true` as integer, not float

Comment: @SlametBedjo: As Rob mentioned, there is no `int` in javascript, just simply a `Number` (`int` is more a determination than a scalar type). And JavaScript only stores what it needs to (and since the two supplied decimal places mean nothing in terms of stating the number `2`, it discards them).

Comment: @BradChristie my mistake, I misunderstood what you meant by "hard-based". Javascript's variables are indeed dynamic and not strongly typed.

Comment: i know just there is NUMBER. but, we want to create function isInt() . and 2.00 always true as int. not float

Comment: @SlametBedjo: Well, since JS doesnt have an `int` or a `float` you have to work with how `Number` works (and formats when necessary).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Number.toFixed(n);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var i = 2;

alert( i.toFixed(2) ); // "2.00"
```

---

```
var i = 1.2345;

alert( i.toFixed(2) ); // "1.23"
```

---

Also note that `2 === 2.00` but `2 !== "2.00"`.

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` cast the number `i` to a string telling that you want two decimal points

Comment: @SlametBedjo .toFixed(2) will return a string. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Thank you :) . yes, only number.
But.. the case is, we want to detect 2.00 as float, not as integer. we create function isInt, but, 2.00 true as int, not float

Comment: @SlametBedjo Please go and read about JavaScript(http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp), as others have mentioned, there are no ints or floats in javascript. Only Numbers. To detect if a Number has decimal places, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: @SlametBedjo That's not how JavaScript works cause a number covers both integers and floats and all remaining zeros will be removed from a number `0.01 == 0.010 == 0.01000000000`. You connot detect how the number was initialized eg `var i = 2.00`.

Comment: @Rob You should consider checking out Mozilla Developer Network (mdn) - also a good reference and maintained by the users (wiki)

Comment: @NULL I do, link provided as just to show the different data-types to OP.

Answer (score 0):

To stringify (Chrome at least does so) use this:

```
i.toPrecision(3)
```

This will show 2 decimal digits.

Also NULL's solution does it very well without having to calculate the exact precision. i.e. `.toFixed(decimals)` is your best friend

Comment: @Powerslace `.toPrecision` will return a string with length = (length + dec float) of a number `(12.34).toPrecision(3) === "12.3"`

Comment: Further, it goes into `e` notation `1234..toPrecision(3); // 1.23e+3`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want to do.

2.00 gets converted to the number 2 in JavaScript, without decimal points. You can add it back in if you want using .toFixed(2), shown above.

Comment: because JS only know them as number, The case is, how to detect 2.00 as float, not as int (when you create isInt() function)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping "2.00" as a string, as well as parsing it as a number, if necessary, for arithmetic. That way you can distinguish whether the number 2 was entered as "2", or "2.00", or "2.000000". Output the string, not the number, if you want to preserve the original number of decimal places.