# jQuery Validation, Numeric Value Only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a form input value. The function below states is the value of the input is a number below 150, show error. Works as it should. However, I want to add to it. If the value contains ANYTHING other than a numeric value AND/OR is a value under 150, show error...

How can I modify?

```
if ($('.billboard-height').val() < 150) {
    $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
}
```

Comment: why dont you just prevent any input other than numeric, that way they cant press on anything but 0-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your more thorough validation should be on the server-side anyway, you could just use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) depending on what sort of value you are expecting. Then check if the result is actually a number and that it also meets your constraints:

```
var number = parseFloat($('.billboard-height').val()); // or parseInt depending on expected input
if (isNaN(number) || number < 150) {
    $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, you are entering regex land. I gather you only ever want a natural number (and the way parseInt/parseFloat ignores trailing non-numeric characters like px, em, etc. is not ok). How about:

```
var val = $('.billboard-height').val();
var number = parseInt(val, 10);
if ( ! val.match(/^[0-9]{3,4}$/) || number < 150) {
    $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
}
```

This should only allow natural numbers 150-9999.

Comment: I like this! Clean and simple!

Comment: In short, the .billboard-height is a pixel value for the height...but I only want numerics to be entered through the text input, as the px is added separately. Your code prevents some typing in 460px for example, but the `$('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);` won't display.  It only will IF the value is below 150

Comment: I want to prevent people from entering `px, %, or em`, etc in the text field.

Comment: @MikeBarwick - Not sure if SO automatically notifies you of edits but I added one that hopefully hits the spot.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using regexes:

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
if(intRegex.test(str) || floatRegex.test(str)) {
   alert('I am a number');
   ...
}
```

Or with a single regex as per @Platinum Azure's suggestion:

```
var numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;
var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
if(numberRegex.test(str)) {
   alert('I am a number');
   ...
}
```

ref: [checking if number entered is a digit in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272696/checking-if-number-entered-is-a-digit-in-jquery)

Comment: Those regexes seem over-complicated... To test an int you can just make sure there is no match on this regex: `[^0-9-]`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the radix parameter in parseInt():

```
if (parseInt($('.billboard-height').val(), 10) < 150) {
```

It's probably faster than using a regex. Regular expressions are not known for being fast, but they are very powerful. It might be overkill for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [HTML5's built in form validation](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html):

```
<input type="number" min="150">
```

[browser support is still pretty shakey though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try **parseInt** and **isNaN** functions for check if value is number and less than `150`:

```
var intVal = parseInt($('.billboard-height').val());
if(!isNaN(intVal)){ //not Number
    if (parseInt($('.billboard-height').val()) < 150) { //not less than 150
        $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Displays an alert if s contains a non-numeric character.

function alertForNonNumeric(s) {
    var rgx = /[^0-9]/;
    if (s.search(rgx) !== -1) {
        alert("Input contains non-numeric characters!");
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjaDK/2)

**NOTE**: If you want to check for negative ints as well, you can add a minus sign to the regex:

```
function alertForNonNumeric(s) {
    var rgx = /[^0-9-]/;
    if (s.search(rgx) !== -1) {
        alert(s + " contains non-numeric characters!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any value from an input or select will be a string in javascript. You need to use `parseInt()` to use operators like `>` or `<`. `==` can be used if you use it to compare to a string like `if ($('.billboard-height').val() == "150")`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support floating point numbers, you can check if a variable is valid using:

```
function isNumber (n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var val = $('.billboard-height').val();
if (isNumber(val) && parseFloat(val) < 150) {
    $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
}
```

If you only need to support integers, use `parseInt(n, 10)`, where 10 is the base to convert the string to.

```
var val = parseInt($('.billboard-height').val(), 10);
if (val && val < 150) {
    $('.sb-billboardalert').fadeIn(600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution, I find it quite ellegant - no alerts, user is effectively unable to enter non numeric characters.

This is jQuery example:

```
function digitsOnly(){
    // extract only numbers from input    
    var num_val = $('#only_numbers').val().match(/\d+/);
         $('#only_numbers').val(num_val);
    }
```

Your html:

```
<input type="text" name="only_numbers" id="only_numbers" on oninput="digitsOnly();"/>
```