# controlling keyboard input when clicking on keyboard

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET with jQuery. I have a TextBox and I will insert only float values, i.e: `11.33`. I'll control the inserted characters from keyboard when writing the value `11.33`. If the user enters a character which is not a number or a '.', then the TextBox should ignore it and not insert it.

How can I do?

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272696/checking-if-number-entered-is-a-digit-in-jquery

Comment: sorry,thank you I took your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this jquery method

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Edit: It is always also better to double check back at the server side, which means adding validation code at your code behind also

Comment: Assalam Hasan thank :-)