# Check if value entered is a valid integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the value entered by the user is a valid integer using jquery

I have tried this code but it always seems to return **true**:

```
if ((manageridEntered === "") || ($.isNumeric(manageridEntered))) {
  success = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/? It states: "[...] $.isNumeric() returns true only if the argument is of type number, or if it's of type string and it can be coerced into finite numbers. In all other cases, it returns false."

Comment: @gus27 Can you try with number  followed by alphabets? Eg:- 2ab show IsNumeric true, this is wrong na?

Answer (score 4):

You could use classic JavaScript :

```
var isNumber = Number.isInteger(yournumber);
```

Or if you want to check if it isn't (without using `!`) :

```
var isNaN = Number.isNaN(yournumber);
```

```js
console.log(Number.isInteger(0.1));       // false
console.log(Number.isInteger(1));         // true
console.log(Number.isInteger(-100000));   // true
console.log(Number.isInteger(Math.PI));   // false
console.log(Number.isInteger(-Infinity)); // false
console.log(Number.isInteger(true));      // false
console.log(Number.isInteger(NaN));       // false
console.log(Number.isInteger(0));         // true
console.log(Number.isInteger("10"));      // false
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `jquery`

You can use `javascript` `isNaN()`

> isNaN() accepts decimal numbers also

```
return !isNaN(manageridEntered))
```

**or**

You can use plain `javascript` `regex` here to match only digits

```
return new RegExp('^\\d+$').test(manageridEntered))
```

Comment: The approach with `isNaN` will also return true for floats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vanilla JavaScript:

```
success = !manageridEntered.length || parseInt(manageridEntered) == manageridEntered;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
if(Math.floor(manageridEntered) == manageridEntered && $.isNumeric(manageridEntered)){
     //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
if(intRegex.test(str) || floatRegex.test(str)) {
   alert('I am a number');

}
```

Example taken from [checking if number entered is a digit in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272696/checking-if-number-entered-is-a-digit-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

`isNumeric` is checking for a number (which could be wrapped in a string too), not an integer. Beside that `isNumeric()` is not **always** returning true like you can see in the following snippet using **JQuery 2.1.1**.

```js
console.log($.isNumeric('a'));    // false
console.log($.isNumeric('1'));    // true
console.log($.isNumeric(1));      // true
console.log($.isNumeric(1.5));    // true
console.log($.isNumeric('1.5'));  // true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
  var Number = $('#Number').val();
if ((Number === "") || ($.isNumeric(Number))) {
  alert('Valid NUmber');
}else{
  alert('Not Valid NUmber');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
   Inateger Value: <input type="text" name="Number" id="Number" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitBtn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you can achieve it see below code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").on("click", function () {

                var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");
                if (patt.test($("#number").val())) {
                    alert("true")
                } else {
                    alert("false")
                }
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="button" id="button"  value="Check"/>
```

Comment: I have used this method, but it has still not picked my input up as a valid number

Comment: @user1483145 might be something you are missing you can see above code snippet is working fine

Answer (score 0):

returns `true` if it's an integer

```
if(manageridEntered == parseInt(manageridEntered))
```